# Alter a column to indicate there are duplicates in a separate column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table in which one of the columns, column_A has duplicate values. I also have a blank column_indicator which I would like to populate with 1s for all cases where the value in column_A occurs more than once.

I know how to SELECT the duplicates and have used the following formula:

```
SELECT [dbo].[myTable].[column_A], COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[myTable]
GROUP BY [dbo].[myTable].[column_A]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

How do I update column_indicator? I have tried:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable]
SET [dbo].[myTable].[column_indicator] = 1
WHERE
GROUP BY [dbo].[myTable].[column_A]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I know I am off base but cannot figure out how to proceed with this column update.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a window count in a common table expression and then update it:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        [column_indicator],
        [column_A], 
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [column_A]) cnt
    FROM [dbo].[myTable]
)
UPDATE cte SET [column_indicator] = 1 WHERE cnt > 1
```

Comment: I received the error message Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "~[myTable].[column_indicator]~" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use a nested update query to solve this.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[myTable] SET [column_indicator] = 1  
FROM  
(  
    SELECT a.[column_A],a.[column_indicator], COUNT(*) AS COUNT 
    FROM (select [dbo].[myTable].[column_A],[dbo].[myTable].[column_indicator]
      from [dbo].[myTable]) a
    GROUP BY a.[column_A],a.[column_indicator]
    having COUNT > 1
) t  
WHERE [dbo].[myTable].[column_A] = t.[column_A];
```

Comment: I just tried and got Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: I changed the table reference to be an alias table in the code above. See if this fixes the issue.